# Working with text fields in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am making a search form with a number of free text fields that I would like the user to edit in line on a tableview (and not go to a seperate view for each individual item). So far I have it so when you press on the field, a text input dialog appears, here is the relevant code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 130, 25)];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        label.tag = kLabelTag;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
        [label release];

        UITextField *theTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 10, 140, 25)];
        theTextField.tag = kTextFieldTag;
        theTextField.delegate = self;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:theTextField];
        [theTextField release];
```

This has the desired effect of allowing a user to press a row and get an edit dialog, but I have a few problems:

1) You can see I have set the text field's delegate to equal self. The class this is run in implements UITextFieldDelegate yet `textFieldShouldEndEditing` is not being fired.

2)How can i realisticly persist what the user puts in memory. In other words, is it possible to find out which text field the user has selected currently so i can go `[myArray getObjectAtIndex:blah]` and edit the actual data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) Are the other delegate methods being called?

2) You can for example set the `tag` attribute on each text field to identify them, and use that as an index into the array.